# JPA Criteria Builder

Tags: jpa-2.0, jpql

Currently , I am doing some JPA stuff, but having some problem, as described below **:**

**Table Structure-**

**`Id(Integer) , StatusType(String) , CreationTime(TimeStamp)`**

I want to extract **StatusType** , **Count(StatusType)** and **CreationTime[GROUP BY]**`(Cast in Date instead of TimeStamp)`

if CreationTime is grouped in TimeStamp then no grouping is done because of uniqueness of the timestamp

I have a sql query that solves my purpose - **`Select StatusType , Count(*) , Date(CreationTime) from Table Group By Date(CreationTime)`**

It casts Timestamp to Date & group by CreationTime,
but I want this to be with **CriteriaBuilder** API or at least in **JPQL Query** ,  so that it works for all Database. Any idea about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you may cast the timestamp to a integer with "yyyyMMdd" format, by using:

```
year(CreateTime) * 10000 + month(CreateTime) * 100 + day(CreateTime)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `timeStamp` can be casted to `Date` using JPQL.

I think [this blog post](http://solitarygeek.com/java/extracting-only-date-part-of-a-date-time-column-using-jpa-hibernate) will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the blog link. But this is using Hibernate api which is not available in JPA specification using Eclipse link.And I wanted to do this using JPQL query or Criteria query which follow Sun's JPA specification standards.Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks again for your help.